# If the kernel is a finite set then the mapping is injective?

Tags: linear-algebra

Fix T ∈ L(V, W) where the field is R and Ker(T) is a finite set. Then T is injective.

I know that if the kernel of T is 0 then the mapping is injective, but if it's just a finite set then the kernel is not guaranteed to be 0. My question is if the kernel is not 0 can the mapping still be injective? Also to that end, why can you say that if the kernel is a finite set then the mapping must be injective?

Thank you

Comment: **Hint:** the kernel is a subspace of $V$,

Comment: If R is finite, V = R and W = 0, then the kernel of the zero morphism is finite.

Comment: When you wrote $R$, did you mean $\Bbb R$?